# Expresso Store & Sagepage 3107 BillingsSurname Error

Tags: expresso-store

I am guessing this is similar to the question [Expresso Store: SagePay Server rejecting missing BillingSurname](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5163/expresso-store-sagepay-server-rejecting-missing-billingsurname)
 in some ways, thou the solution on this entry does not apply anymore with Store 2.+

If I hard code in a billings_name hidden field into the details page before review then the system works else it get this error from SagePay. Currently I have a first/last name setup with the details and this is reflected with in the store fields settings.

Am i missing a configuration ?

Comment: Can you confirm what version of Store you're currently using? If you're running Store v2 and have both `billing_first_name` and `billing_last_name` in your template with valid content then it *should* work fine.   Can you confirm both are being submitted?

Comment: Yes i'm using the latest version 2.3.1  - billing_first_name and billing_last_name are both in the template.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a `payment[card_name]` field being submitted on the last page of your checkout?

Comment: Tested again and it seems to be working.. tested adding and removing the payment[card*] fields and this causes the error. Possibly a bug ? I would have assume this would not have effected the sage pay process. _Thanks Adrian_

Answer (score 0):

For expresso 2.3.1 SagePay will return a error of - 3107 BillingsSurname if the card details form is present on the review template. I guess this is because the payment[card_name] is used instead of billings_first_name & bilings_last_name.   Removing or commenting out this form will resolve this issue.

*Thanks Adrian Macneil for the solution*